# Is there a possibility to find when was the last time user has accessed CRMA dashboard

Tags: crm-analytics

I am trying to find out when has each user with dashboard access has last run/open the dashboard to remove the access for the users to the dashboard who don't use it frequently. Is there a way i can find it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have Event Monitoring(Shield) enabled to get this info from [Wave Interaction Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_waveinteraction.htm)